# Sequelize time comparison failed after database replacement to postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I've replaced MySQL database instead PostgreSQL and now I have issue when I'm trying find user through :

```
.find({ where: { resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { gt: Date.now() } } })
.then(function(user){
  if (!user) {
    req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.' });
    return res.redirect('/forgot');
  }
 res.render('account/reset', {
    title: 'Password Reset'
  });
})
.catch(function(err){
  return next(err);
});
```

**This code was working before now I've message:**

`SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone > bigint`

Date inside database is stored like: 2015-03-05 08:09:40.152+01

[image]

I will be very grateful because I don't know if my issue is caused by database migration or some type in my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Date.now() to new Date(), looks like before you were storing time as integer.

```
{ gt: new Date() }
```